# constructing hemisphere in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I had to construct hemisphere in MATLAB ,so I did this:

```
figure  
k = 5;
n = 2^k-1;
theta = pi*(-n:2:n)/n;
phi = (pi/2)*(0:2:n)'/n;
X = cos(phi)*cos(theta);
Y = cos(phi)*sin(theta);
Z = sin(phi)*ones(size(theta));  

surf(X,Y,Z);
```

[image]

The code was not written by me so I want to understand this,when I replace ' in
`phi = (pi/2)*(0:2:n)'/n;`
I get following error :
`operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x16, op2 is 1x32)`

Please explain why is it essential....
Also,I wanted to write an easier code for sketching hemisphere.any idea for some shorter command/method I can use in matlab....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'`-sign is the transpose. If you matrix-multiply a 16-by-1 array by a 1-by-32, you end up with a 16-by-32 array, where element `(i,j)` is the ith-element of the first array multiplied with the jth element of the second array. If you omit the transpose, you're trying to matrix-multiply a 1-by-16 array with an 1-by-32 array, which is undefined in linear algebra. Using linear algebra like this is one way to create grids of numbers in Matlab.

An alternative approach is to create the grids via `ndgrid`, for example:

```
[theta,phi] = ndgrid(pi*(-n:2:n)/n, (pi/2)*(0:2:n)/n);
X = cos(phi).*cos(theta); 
...
```

Note that I used the element-wise multiplication `.*`, since I'm not doing linear algebra here.

To your second question: If the code you posted is too long, the easiest is to put it into a function, so that you can create the plot via a one-line function call.

Comment: @coool: You're welcome. I should have asked first: do you know linear algebra?

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract: glad you do, b/c otherwise, my explanation would not have made a lot of sense to you :)